# ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium when trying to automate browser

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, exception, browser

When I am trying to enter the input in the given field I get an error saying

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input class="text-input email-input js-signin-email" name="session[username_or_email]" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I tried increasing the `timer.sleep()` from 10 seconds to 15 seconds. I found no fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit wait instead:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


input_filed = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.text-input.email-input.js-signin-email")))
# Do actions with input element.
```

Hope it helps you!